# importing tbl file to monetDB on windows 10

Tags: windows, monetdb

I am having trouble importing the data of the TPCH-Benchmark (generated with dbgen) into my monetDB-Database.
I've already created all the tables and I'm trying to import using the following command:

> COPY RECORDS INTO region FROM "PATH\region.tbl" DELIMITERS tuple_seperator '|' record_seperator '\r\n';

And I get the following error message:

> syntax error, unexpected RECORDS, expecting BINARY or INTO in: "copy records"

*I also found out this one on the internet:*

> COPY INTO sys.region 'PATH/region.tbl' using delimiters '|','\n';

But I get the following error message:

> syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting FROM in: "copy into sys.region "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\region."

Because I'm a new monetDB user I'm not getting

What I'm doing wrong ?

Any help will be appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RECORDS construct expects a number, specifically how many records you are to load. I usually do this:

```
COPY 5 RECORDS INTO region FROM '/path/to/region.tbl' USING DELIMITERS '|', '|\n' LOCKED;
```

Also in the second attempt you are missing a FROM before the path to the file like

```
COPY INTO sys.region FROM '/path/to/region.tbl' USING DELIMITERS '|', '\n';
```

See here for more information: https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/CopyInto

Comment: thanks, i got it with the second one, i forgot the "FROM"  -.-" and one more delimiter "\r"